# How to show message box after uploading a file which size is bigger than limit size instead of showing IE page error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, file-upload, filesize

In my project, I have FileUpload control and upload button. I want to limit the file size at 10MB so I put the following code in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="10240" />
</system.web>
```

I also put try/catch block in upload button click method as follows:

```
Private Sub Upload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Attach.Click
    Try
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim fileSize As Integer = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength
            If (fileSize < 10485760) Then
                Select_id = ViewState("Select_id")
                typename = CInt(ViewState("typename"))
                If Select_id.HasValue Then
                    UploadFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile)
                End If
            Else
                ShowMessageBox(Me.Parent.Page, "File size cannot be greater than 10MB.")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ShowMessageBox(Me.Parent.Page, ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

As I tested the function, it works correctly for the file which size is less than 10MB. In contrast, the file which size is greater than 10MB cause page error, stating that "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". It didn't even enter the button click method when I tried debugging.

Right now, it is not really a big problem. I just want to know how to show message box of error instead of redirecting to IE error page. If there is no solution for this, I'll just leave it be.

Comment: you are using web or windows application?
what is your button id?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I'm using web application. My button id is "btn_Attach".

Comment: Anyway, I just got an idea from my teammate. He suggested me to increase maxRequestLength higher than 10MB and then check the file size later in code-behind before uploading. It works very well.